# importing a file within visual studio code

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to make a file within visual studio code that holds my API key and secret key. so when I do future codes I can just import that file into my code without having to write my API keys every time.

I've tried this

api key = 'cewhjhbdhbd'
secret key = 'jhewbduywevb'

tried to save it.. it saved in documents and when I tried to import it nothing happened.. where am I going wrong?

I am a beginner at coding so sorry if this is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use environment variables for this.

```
import os

# Set environment variables
os.environ['API_USER'] = 'username'
os.environ['API_PASSWORD'] = 'secret'

# Get environment variables
USER = os.getenv('API_USER')
PASSWORD = os.environ.get('API_PASSWORD')
```

You can then import this file or use the above block of code in your files.

Comment: By using env variables, you can use this in other projects as well

Answer (score 0):

Use an environment file like **.env** to store your API keys. In a format like

```
ENVIRONMENT='DEVELOPMENT'
API_KEY='yourapikeygoeshere'
DEBUG=True
DB_NAME=''
DB_USER=''
DB_PASSWORD=''
DB_HOST='localhost'
DB_PORT='5432'
```

Then you can use packages like **dotenv** to access them.

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path

dotenv_path = Path('path/to/.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=dotenv_path)
API_KEY = os.getenv('API_KEY')
```